# package-lock.json has links like git://github.com/danteata/passport-oauth.git

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am using AWS Amplify, when I push code of react to my branch, CI/CD runs and on "npm install" build fails on AWS Amplify, with error

> npm
> 2022-01-11T09:31:06.876Z [WARNING]: ERR! Error while executing:
> npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t git://github.com/danteata/passport-oauth.git
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! fatal: remote error:
> npm ERR!   The unauthenticated git protocol on port 9418 is no longer supported.
> npm ERR! Please see https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/ for more information.
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

I've also tried to replce git://git.. with https://git.... in package-lock.json (suggested by https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/) but the build fails with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

We got over this by adding `git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://` to the Build Specification amplify.yml preBuild commmands (just before `npm install`).

See below:

**amplify.yml**

```
...
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
        - npm install
...
```